# golang user.Lookup on a long hostname (more than 15 characters)

Tags: windows, go, hostname

I have some code that is looking up a user SID. The code is simply

`user.Lookup(username)`

where username is computername\username. This works great... until you have a computer with a name longer than 15 characters. Then I have to shorten it to the first 15 characters. So this leads me to two questions:

1. Is there any way to get it to work with the full computer name?
2. Isn't there a conflict if the domain and computer name share the first 15 characters?

Comment: Stop. Deleting. My. Comments.

Answer (score 1):

When doing a lookup with `computername\username` the NETBIOS name of the computer is used and not the DNS hostname. The NETBIOS name is limited to 15 characters. This is a limitation based on the design of NETBIOS and thus of the underlying Windows system and has nothing to do with Go and can therefore also not bypassed by Go.

See [Naming conventions in Active Directory for computers, domains, sites, and OUs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and)
 for more information.

Comment: And the second question?

Comment: @Andrew: A NETBIOS name has only 15 characters, i.e. there is no "sharing first 15 characters" but they are either equal or not.

Comment: I don't understand... if I have a domain that is a23456789012345 and a computer that is a234567890123456, what's the difference between hostname\user and domain\user?

Comment: @Andrew: not sure, but I think in this case (same computer and domain name) you would need to be more clear what you mean, i.e. use `user@domain.local` or similar instead.